# When inputting the correct input, if statement doesn't work with DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, w3.css

I was wondering why this doesn't work: when I input "1234" and press the button nothing happens. Can anyone help me with this?

```html
<head>
    <title>Your Website!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="w3-container w3-green w3-center"> | YOUR WEBSITE | </h1>
    <h3 class="w3-aqua w3-spin w3-left">AMAZING</h3>
    <h2 class="w3-green w3-center">Type in "1234"</h2>
    <input id="inputArea"></input>
    <button class="w3-btn w3-red" onclick="pressed()">Try it</button>
    <script>
        function pressed() {
            var i = document.getElementById(inputArea).value;
            if (i = "1234") {
                alert("PASSWORD CORRECT");
            }else {
                alert("PASSWORD INCORRECT");
            }

        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: It seems like `inputArea` is a reference to an HTML ID. As a string, it needs quotes like `getElementById("inputArea")`. Also, `i = "1234"` [assigns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment) the variable, whereas `i == "1234"` tests for [equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You forgot to put the input id between ".
Here is the working code:

```
  <head>
    <title>Your Website!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="w3-container w3-green w3-center"> | YOUR WEBSITE | </h1>
    <h3 class="w3-aqua w3-spin w3-left">AMAZING</h3>
    <h2 class="w3-green w3-center">Type in "1234"</h2>
    <input id="inputArea"></input>
    <button class="w3-btn w3-red" onclick="pressed()">Try it</button>
    <script>
        function pressed() {
            var i = document.getElementById("inputArea").value;
            if (i = "1234") {
                alert("PASSWORD CORRECT");
            }else {
                alert("PASSWORD INCORRECT");
            }

        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Please don't answer questions where the solution is "Fix the typo". This type of question has no long term value since other people with the same problem are not going to find this by searching. "Typo" is one of the standard Close Vote reasons. Answering this type of question can block the OP from deleting it to remove bloat from StackOverflow. You can delete this answer to remove the possibility of blocking such clean up.

Comment: This code doesn't work. I don't understand why it was accepted as an answer.